# Can I factorise my VirtualHost configurations?

Tags: apache, configuration, httpd.conf, vhosts

I have to make a huge VirtualHost configuration (so there are differents ).
There fews parameters in common to every VirtualHost. So I was wondering if it was possible to build a VirtualHost ()that contains the common parameters. If so, would the "specific"  be given the  parameters ?

Thanks a lot,
Jérémy

Comment: Not that I know of.  At my job, we have a script to build the VirtualHosts, since we have a similar scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use two approaches:

- Use `Include` directives as configuration blocks for static parts of the configuration and include them in various parts. This obviously cant be used to set things like `Directory` blocks since they are dependent on site structure.
- Use [`mod_macro`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_macro.html). From the documentation:

> Provides macros within Apache httpd runtime configuration files, to
>   ease the process of creating numerous similar configuration blocks.
>   When the server starts up, the macros are expanded using the provided
>   parameters, and the result is processed as along with the rest of the
>   configuration file.

This sections will accept parameters and can be combined if needed. .

What I'm not sure if it can do is *freeze* a macro and turn it "magically" into a static configuration file. But since the macro has to be compiled it must be possible.